# Database schema for product quantity

Tags: database, database-design

I have some issues with creating database schema for a following scenario:

Shop, where you configure your order. Let's say user orders flowers and chocolate. So far I had the following structure:

```
OrderID  FK_Flower FK_Chocolate
1         1         1
```

Where FK's pointed to the entry in database such as:

```
Id  Name     Price
1   Rose     100
```

The same for chocolate.

However now, there is a change: use can order multiple different flowers. So let's say, he can order 5 Roses, 3 Daisies.

What changes should I make, to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You want a many-to-many relationship.

Change the Orders table to something like this:

```
Orders:
-------
Id
1
```

The Flowers table stays the same:

```
Flowers:
------------------
Id  Name     Price
1   Rose     100
2   Daisy    120
```

Create a new table with with the Order and Flower ID's as foreign keys:

```
Orders_Flowers:
-------------------------
FK_Order_Id  FK_Flower_ID
1            1
1            1
1            1
1            1
1            1
1            2
1            2
1            2
```

This way, the Order with Id = 1, has 5 Roses and 3 Daisies.